# Integral of $(-0.53\sqrt[3]{x-16.7}+2.8)^2$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I require some help integrating this function for a modelling project and not really sure where to start.
$$f(x)=(-0.53\sqrt[3]{x-16.7}+2.8)^2$$
I started by converting the decimals into fractions to see if it would be easier, however I am stuck. Fraction form:
$$f(x)=(-\frac {53\sqrt[3]{x-\frac{167}{10}}}{100}+\frac{14}{5})^2$$

I have also tried to take out the denominators in order to simplify the question however I am not sure I have done that correctly. I believe I can take out the $5$ from $\frac{14}{5}$ as $\frac{1}{25}$ and the 100 under the cube root as $10^4$. I also think I can take out the $10$ from inside the cube root to give me $10^{2\over3}$. This  means the function can be rewritten as:
$${1\over25*10^{14\over3}}(- {265\sqrt[3]{10x-{167}}}+14*10^{7\over3})^2 $$
Would this be right and where would I go from here?
Can I also take out negative one to give me:
$${{1*-1^2}\over25*10^{14\over3}}({265\sqrt[3]{10x-{167}}}-14*10^{7\over3})^2 $$

Comment: Expand the squared parenthesis. Then use a change of variable $y=x-16.7$. You should have an integral with $y^\frac23$, and integral with $y^\frac13$ and an integral of a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiation and integration are linear. Unlike performing arithmetic, writing the constants in terms of decimals or fraction won't change your calculation.

The constants are really distractions. Write

$$
f(x)=(a\sqrt[3]{x-b}+c)^2. 
$$
Let $u=a\sqrt[3]{x-b}+c$. Then
$$
(\frac{u-c}{a})^3+b=x,\quad dx = 3(\frac{u-c}{a})^2\frac{1}{a}\;du
$$

Now you can calculate $\int f(x)\;dx$ by a u-[substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution):
$$
\int f(x)\;dx = \int u^2\cdot3(\frac{u-c}{a})^2\frac{1}{a}\;du
=\frac{3}{a^3}\int u^2(u-c)^2\;du 
$$
which is easy since you now have a polynomial to integrate.

Comment: This is very insightful. I haven't thought about it this way. I'll give it a try. Thanks.